# YouTube-dl is updated to latest version.when I am running this code this long weird error is occurex

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl, pafy

```
import pafy
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFzOA0-jfOo"
v= pafy.new(url)
print(v.title)
```

ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1399, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 627, in _request_webpage
    return self._downloader.urlopen(url_or_request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2238, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2726, in https_open
    return self.do_open(functools.partial(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1681, in _real_extract
    video_webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 791, in _download_webpage
    res = self._download_webpage_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 271, in _download_webpage_handle
    return super(YoutubeBaseInfoExtractor, self)._download_webpage_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 660, in _download_webpage_handle
    urlh = self._request_webpage(url_or_request, video_id, note, errnote, fatal, data=data, headers=headers, query=query, expected_status=expected_status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 645, in _request_webpage
    raise ExtractorError(errmsg, sys.exc_info()[2], cause=err)
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 40, in _fetch_basic
    self._ydl_info = ydl.extract_info(self.videoid, download=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "YtDow.py", line 3, in 
    v= pafy.new(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 124, in new
    return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts=ydl_opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 31, in **init**
    super(YtdlPafy, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_shared.py", line 97, in **init**
    self._fetch_basic()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 43, in _fetch_basic
    raise IOError(str(e).replace('YouTube said', 'Youtube says'))
OSError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
venkatrimmalapudi@Venkats-MacBook-Air python % vi YtDow.py
venkatrimmalapudi@Venkats-MacBook-Air python % python3 YtDow.py
ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1399, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 627, in _request_webpage
    return self._downloader.urlopen(url_or_request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2238, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2726, in https_open
    return self.do_open(functools.partial(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1681, in _real_extract
    video_webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 791, in _download_webpage
    res = self._download_webpage_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 271, in _download_webpage_handle
    return super(YoutubeBaseInfoExtractor, self)._download_webpage_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 660, in _download_webpage_handle
    urlh = self._request_webpage(url_or_request, video_id, note, errnote, fatal, data=data, headers=headers, query=query, expected_status=expected_status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 645, in _request_webpage
    raise ExtractorError(errmsg, sys.exc_info()[2], cause=err)
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 40, in _fetch_basic
    self._ydl_info = ydl.extract_info(self.videoid, download=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "YtDow.py", line 3, in 
    v= pafy.new(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 124, in new
    return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts=ydl_opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 31, in **init**
    super(YtdlPafy, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_shared.py", line 97, in **init**
    self._fetch_basic()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 43, in _fetch_basic
    raise IOError(str(e).replace('YouTube said', 'Youtube says'))
OSError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
venkatrimmalapudi@Venkats-MacBook-Air python % vi YtDow.py
venkatrimmalapudi@Venkats-MacBook-Air python % python3 YtDow.py
ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1399, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 627, in _request_webpage
    return self._downloader.urlopen(url_or_request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2238, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2726, in https_open
    return self.do_open(functools.partial(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1681, in _real_extract
    video_webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 791, in _download_webpage
    res = self._download_webpage_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 271, in _download_webpage_handle
    return super(YoutubeBaseInfoExtractor, self)._download_webpage_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 660, in _download_webpage_handle
    urlh = self._request_webpage(url_or_request, video_id, note, errnote, fatal, data=data, headers=headers, query=query, expected_status=expected_status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 645, in _request_webpage
    raise ExtractorError(errmsg, sys.exc_info()[2], cause=err)
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 40, in _fetch_basic
    self._ydl_info = ydl.extract_info(self.videoid, download=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "YtDow.py", line 3, in 
    v= pafy.new(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 124, in new
    return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts=ydl_opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 31, in **init**
    super(YtdlPafy, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_shared.py", line 97, in **init**
    self._fetch_basic()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 43, in _fetch_basic
    raise IOError(str(e).replace('YouTube said', 'Youtube says'))
OSError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

Answer (score 2):

You can add `ydl_opts={'nocheckcertificate': True}` in the `pafy.new` command.It can be written as

> `v = pafy.new(url,ydl_opts={'nocheckcertificate': True})`

You can find this in [github issues](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/issues/148).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

do a global search for a file named `Install Certificates.command`. It is located inside python folder. Double click on it and the error should disappear